# How do I save previous activity when starting a new intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two activities. One is the homepage with a button to add a dynamic button and the second page is two edit texts. So you click the button on the homepage and go to the second page where you input two edit texts and youre sent back to the homepage where a dynamic button set to one of the edit text is created. I made an inflator that allows you to go back into the second activity through the button but it starts a new second activity so the previous inputted edit texts are gone. How do I get them to stay?

Main page:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java), questionActivityCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == questionActivityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            createNewButtonWithText(data?.getStringExtra("test") ?: "")
        }
    }

    private fun createNewButtonWithText(text: String)
    {
        val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
        newbutton.text = text
        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        layout.addView(newbutton)

        val inflator = layoutInflater
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)

        newbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text, null)
            with(builder) {
                setTitle(newbutton.text)
                setPositiveButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog, which ->
                    Log.d("Main", "Negative button clicked")
                }
                setView(dialogLayout)
                show()
        }
    }
}}
```

Second Activity:

```
    package com.example.quest

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener {
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()
            val answertext = answer.text.toString()
            val sharedPre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this@SecondActivity).edit()
            sharedPre.putString("question", questiontext)
            sharedPre.putString("answer", answertext)
            sharedPre.apply()


            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the activity lifecycle after creating an activity and when moving from one activity to the next activity the activity is destroyed, and a new activity is created. An easy way to save this data could be to use shared preferences whereby you can store the data when the user inputs it in the second activity and before you inflate the second activity check if the sharedprefs data is not null and use the data to update the activity else just create a new activity.

Comment: I tried shared preferences but for some reason it wasnt working. Can you please show me a sample code that could work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVVM architecture? You should probably store all your value in `ViewModel` and call these values between activities in `ViewModel`, as View (Actiity/Fragment) is only responsible for UI-related task.

Here is a simple example

SharedViewModel

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

   // ViewModel that holds data-related values
   var question: String ?= null
   var answer: Stirng ?= null   

}
```

SecondActivity

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels() <-- add your viewmodel here

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)


        // Step 1 - Check viewmodel's value and assign it back to edittext
        if(sharedViewModel.question != null) {
            question.text = sharedViewModel.question
        } 

        if(sharedViewModel.answer != null) {
            answer.text = sharedViewModel.answer
        }

        // Step 2 - Assign your value into viewmodel
        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener {

            sharedViewModel.question = question.text.toString()
            sharedViewModel.answer = answer.text.toString()
            
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }

    }
```

**Additional**

1. `onActivityResult` will be deprecated soon in API 30, it it better you can learn `ActivityResultContract`
2. Try to use `databinding` as it helps to reduce many of the boilerplate since you're using kotlin.
3. Try to adapt to `MVVM architecture` as it helps you a lot in developing Android app.

Comment: is this the correct answer to you? or what do you still need? Please give me some feedback. Thanks